# What does the default helm create chart do?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

*Does the default helm chart actually run and do something I can observe?*

**I've tried running it (the default helm chart) and it does run; So, what does it do?**

To recreate the problem I'm asking about, do the following:

```
helm create helm-it                 # Create a helm chart (the default)
helm install helm-it ./helm-it      # Run it
helm list                           # See it running
helm get manifest helm-it           # See the manifest (YAML) that is running (I think)
```

By examining the manifest (using `helm get manifest helm-it`), I can see how it's configured.  The important bit is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: helm-it
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: helm-it-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: helm-it
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: helm-it
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: helm-it
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: helm-it
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: helm-it
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: helm-it
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: helm-it
      securityContext:
        {}
      containers:
        - name: helm-it
          securityContext:
            {}
          image: "nginx:1.16.0"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          resources:
            {}
```

It seems to be running nginx on port 80 but when trying to access it using curl, I got an error (see output below).

```
curl http://localhost:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

#### I looked for a solution

- When looking for a solution I started with the `helm create` documentation at https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_create/
- Searches for `does helm create run` brought up several links for how to create a helm chart in 5 minutes (too many to review) but the answer might be in one of these web pages.

  o https://phoenixnap.com/kb/create-helm-chart - was one of the results.  But it did not answer my question.

#### Why I care

The reason I'm asking is because I'm trying to convert a k8s yaml file into a helm chart and want to know what I'm starting with to know what I can delete and what I need to add.  I found this link:

- [How to convert k8s yaml to helm chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56630871/how-to-convert-k8s-yaml-to-helm-chart) - and it said I could just

> just drop that file under templates/ and add a Chart.yml.

which I tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The templates created by the `helm create` command run Nginx as a stateless application.  I found this in the book *Learning Helm, by Matt Butcher, Matt Farina, Josh Dolitsky* on page 67.  Available in OReilly online books and [Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/mDYWEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=the%20templates%20created%20by%20helm%20create%20command%20run%20Nginx).

To access the NGINX application, you might need to forward data from your host to the K8S cluster.

When performing the `helm install` it gives this output:

```
helm install myapp anvil
NAME: myapp
LAST DEPLOYED: Fri Apr 23 12:23:46 2021
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
NOTES:
1. Get the application URL by running these commands:
  export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace default -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=anvil,app.kubernetes.io/instance
=myapp" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
  export CONTAINER_PORT=$(kubectl get pod --namespace default $POD_NAME -o jsonpath="{.spec.containers[0].ports[0].c
ontainerPort}")
  echo "Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080 to use your application"
  kubectl --namespace default port-forward $POD_NAME 8080:$CONTAINER_PORT
```

The complicated looking commands simply get the name of the pod and the port that is being used by NGINX to create a command that will forward data from your localhost to the kubernetes cluster.  That command is:

```
  kubectl --namespace default port-forward $POD_NAME 8080:$CONTAINER_PORT
```

After `port-forwarding` is running, you can then access `http://localhost:8080/` and get this display that says NGINX is running.  You'll know it's working if the port forwarding displays more logging information.  Mine displayed the following:

```
kubectl --namespace default port-forward $POD_NAME 8080:$CONTAINER_PORT
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 80
Handling connection for 8080
Handling connection for 8080
```

Each time you hit the URL, an additional logging line `Handling connection for 8080` is displayed (and the web page displays the *Welcome to NGINX* page).

[image: NGINX is running]