# How to convert deployment, configmap and service yaml files to helm package

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have an application with many services that are deployed in kubernetes. These services are represented by yaml files like `configmap.yaml` and `deployment.yaml`.

How can I convert these files to helm charts et deploy the application using:

```
helm install
```

Comment: Step one is to just copy the files as-is to the chart's `templates` directory.  They'll pass unchanged through the Helm templating engine.  Is that enough for you?

Comment: thanks, can you please show an exmple with commandes in answer section so that will be a refrence in stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run [`helm create`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_create/) to create a skeleton chart, that will create a basic file structure for you.  Within that chart, the [`templates` directory](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#the-chart-file-structure) contains a set of [templated YAML files](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#template-files).

If you're just getting started, it's enough to move aside the YAML files that `helm create` generates and copy your existing YAML into the `templates` directory.  `helm install` will install those exact files, similar to what `kubectl apply` would do, though note that the specific named resources need to not exist yet in the cluster.

```bash
helm create my-chart
cd my-chart
mkdir original-templates && mv templates/*.yml original-templates
cp ~/application/k8s/*.yml templates
# helm template .
helm install --generate-name .
```

If you do look at the `helm create` template files, you'll notice that there are some conventions on how it chooses things like resource names, calling support functions in the `_helpers.tpl` file that allow installing the chart multiple times in parallel.  A good next step would be to update the `metadata:` blocks in the YAML files to follow these conventions.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "mychart.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "mychart.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  ...
```

From there I'd suggest figuring out what specific things you need to have customized at install time, and replace those with template expressions and specific `values.yaml` settings.  I would not try to inject large parts of the Kubernetes configuration through values, though the boundary can be a little blurry here.  (It makes sense to me to specify a Service type, node port, and annotations through values, but not necessarily a long list of Pod environment variables.)

Answer (score 1):

You can install helm with deployment.yaml files by using helm charts:

1. Create your Helm Chart
2. Convert and Update Chart.yaml, deployment.yaml, service.yaml and values.yaml
3. Verify the Conversion of YAMLs
4. Run/Install Helm Chart

Here in the [document](https://jhooq.com/convert-kubernetes-yaml-into-helm/) you can see the details of each step and process.Attaching the similar [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68766805/how-to-build-helm-chart-from-existing-kubernetes-manifest) for your understanding.